# What is the difference between <xsl:on-non-empty> and <xsl:where-populated> in XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

They appear identical to me. Is there any difference between the two?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b>1<c>Cat</c></b>
   <b>2<c>Cow</c></b>
   <b>3<c>Dog</c></b>
   <b></b>
   <b>4<c>Fish</c></b>
   <b e="9">a<f>s</f></b>   
</a>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"        
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="a/b">
      <xsl:where-populated>
        <xsl:value-of select="c"/>
      </xsl:where-populated>
      <xsl:on-non-empty>
        <xsl:value-of select="c"/>
      </xsl:on-non-empty>
      <xsl:on-empty>EMPTY</xsl:on-empty>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   CatCat
   CowCow
   DogDog
   EMPTY
   FishFish
   EMPTY
```

Also, why is the last line considered "EMPTY"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your sample captures the use case of these instructions, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#where-populated-example is one where the three instructions are used together to construct content. I would say, generally the `xsl:where-populated` wraps a result element container like an `ol` or `ul` or a `table` that is only supposed to be present if there are input items that map to e.g. `li`/list items or `tr`/table rows.

The `xsl:on-none-empty` looks at any sibling content/sequence constructors, or as the text in the spec says: "The `xsl:on-non-empty` instruction is typically used to generate headers or footers appearing before or after a list of items, where the header or footer is to be omitted if there are no items in the list.".

Finally, `xsl:on-empty` looks at whether "every preceding sibling instruction, text node, and literal result element in the same sequence constructor returns either an empty sequence, or a sequence consisting entirely of vacuous items", and only outputs its content in that case.

Comment: So can we safely say this: In general, <xsl:on-non-empty> looks at content generated by its siblings whereas <xsl:where-populated> looks at content generated by its children?

Comment: @ChongLipPhang, yes, at least the purpose is about that, `xsl:where-populated` looks at its contents, `xsl:on-non-empy` looks at content generated by siblings.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the explanations and examples in the spec at

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#where-populated
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-on-non-empty
```

?

The purpose of `where-populated` is to make it easier to avoid generating something like a list or a glossary if it's going to be empty. The problem it solves is that the normal way of doing this:

```
<xsl:if test="exists(glossary-item)">
  <glossary>
     <xsl:for-each select="glossary-item">
        ...
     </xsl:for-each>
  </glossary>
</xsl:if>
```

isn't streamable, because it involves two passes over the glossary contents.

The `on-non-empty` instruction is subtly different: it allows you to output a heading (etc) so long as it's not the only thing present. So you can write

```
  <glossary>
     <xsl:on-non-empty>
       <h1>Here is the glossary</h1>
     </xsl:on-non-empty>
     <xsl:for-each select="glossary-item">
        ...
     </xsl:for-each>
  </glossary>
```

and the h1 will be omitted if no other content is generated. Again, it's provided because the usual way of writing this would involve two passes over the input.